# Saving from a django-leaflet widget

Tags: django, leaflet

I am having trouble saving the point coordinates from a django-leaflet form. I can display the  leaflet widget and add point markers but when I submit the form no geometry is sent. I know this from looking at what is posted back to the server in FireBug. 
e.g. 
csrfmiddlewaretoken 3fOhKMkrlMqIvQfqsq6Myx9agpsif2aQ
geom
name    test
submit  Save

Here is the code:
forms.py

```
from leaflet.forms.fields import MultiPointField
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    geom = MultiPointField()

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['name', 'geom']
```

models.py

```
from leaflet.forms.fields import MultiPointField

class Location(models.Model):

    locationid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    geom = MultiPointField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

template file

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% leaflet_js plugins="forms" %}
{% leaflet_css plugins="forms" %}

<form  id="location_form" method="post" action="/addlocation/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.help_text}}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="login-actions">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">Save</button>
    </div> <!-- .actions -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you missed, in settings:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql', # if use mysql
```

in models:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels
  class Location(gismodels.Model):
```